# Numpy Install on Mac 10.8.4

Tags: python, macos, numpy, osx-mountain-lion

I am new to python/numpy/programming in general. I pip installed numpy. Here's its path:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

Then, when I enter the python shell, I type in import numpy and get:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

This is what it looks like overall:

```
MacBook-Air:desktop tvska$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Cleaning up...
MacBook-Air:desktop tvska$ python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Any advice would really be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python on the machine? Can you supply the data from `which python` and `which pip`?

Comment: I do have multiple versions - 2.3, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 - I'm running 2.7 when I open python, and numpy is located in 2.7. What do you mean by "which pip?

Comment: Simply type `which pip` into a terminal and do the same for python. Im thinking there may be a chance that you did not install pip with python 2.7 so pip is installing numpy into a different python version. Additionally you can check if numpy is in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

Comment: which python: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
and which pip:
/usr/local/bin/pip

Comment: also, when I ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/, all I see is README

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that your pip is linking to the incorrect python version. If `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip` does not exist redownload pip, go to the pip folder and type `python setup.py install`. This will reinstall pip for the current python version (If its a fresh version you may need to install setup tools also).

Check to make sure that your `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` is at the front of your $PATH. I think this is likely the case as it looks like this is a osx binary install and it does this automatically. Then you can use pip to install whatever you need to the correct python version.

If you are not familiar with installations such as these and just want the scipy suite you can download anaconda as an executable from `https://store.continuum.io` and it will setup everything for you.

Comment: so when i go to the pip folder and type in python setup.py install, it tells me that setup.py doesn't exist. "can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: That is very strange. I just double checked that a download from `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip` has everything.

Comment: Let me try again, just a minute.

Comment: MacBook-Air:bin tvska$ sudo easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.3.1
Processing pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
pip 1.3.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin

Comment: and then: 


Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
MacBook-Air:bin tvska$ pwd
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
MacBook-Air:bin tvska$ python setup.py install
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Why are you using `easy_install`? After downloading pip go to the downloaded `pip-1.3.1` folder and type `python setup.py install`. At this point I would recommending downloading anaconda, I have posted the link above.

Comment: sorry about that! ok, downloaded directly from pypi, then opened the folder and typed python setup.py install. got the error:

MacBook-Air:desktop tvska$ cd pip-1.3.1
MacBook-Air:pip-1.3.1 tvska$ python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools

Comment: Yup as mentioned above you will have to install setuptools also: `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools`. Same thing cd into the downloaded setuptools directory and type `python setup.py install`. Do the same for pip, then you should be able to say `pip install numpy` and you will be good to go.